# How to use conditional rendering using class name in React?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

```js
import { display } from '@mui/system';
import React from 'react';
import "../user_config/user_page.css"

export default function FileUploadButton({showBtn, setShowBtn,value,...rest}) {
      const handelClick = () => {
       
        setShowBtn(false);
      };
        return (
            <div style={{ position: 'relative', display: 'inline-block' ,marginTop:'10px'}} className="big-size-file">
                <button  style={{  padding: '1px 12px', border: ' 1px solid #989797', borderRadius: '4px', color: '#727171',cursor:"pointer !important" }}>
                    {value && showBtn ? 'Replace file' : 'Choose file'}
                </button> 
                
                {value && showBtn?<span title={value} style={{fontSize: '9px', color: 'blue', marginLeft:'10px' }}>{value}<button  type="button"  onClick={handelClick} className="float-right  rounded-md text-blue-500 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none " className={"big-size-file"?'marginTop:-17px':'margTop:11px'}>
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    className="h-3 w-3 z-100"
                                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                    fill="currentColor"      
                                >
                                    <path
                                        fillRule="evenodd"
                                        d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                                        clipRule="evenodd"
                                    />
                                </svg>
                            </button></span>:<span>No file chosen</span>}
                <input type='file' {...rest} className="fileStyle" style={{ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2, opacity: 0, height: '100%', top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

also `big-size-file` CSS property

```css
    .big-size-file {
        max-width: 190px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
    }
```

How can I use that `classname` in conditional rendering that if classname is "big-size-file" then button `marginTop` is `-17px` or else `marginTop` `11px`?

Comment: big-size-file classname use for if i am upload biger name file(i.e aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.apk) then it should be ellipsis using three dot (i.e aaaaaaaa...)

Comment: if i want to upload small file (i.e file1.apk) then the button position is not aligned so manually i have to change the margin-top:17px; also if i upload bigger file like(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.apk)then button position position i have to fixed 11px ,so i just want a condition that if user upload small file  then button is aligned as well as if upload bigger file then also aligned so manually two file are aligned  parallelly

Comment: so  i want that if classname is "big-size-file" then margintop -17px else margintop 11px    like <span className={"big-size-file"?'marginTop:-17px':'margTop:11px'}>

Comment: "big-size-file "comes form external CSS file user_page.css that already import in my file

Comment: I guess just apply the `'marginTop: -17px'` style because the string literal "big-size-file" is a truthy defined value, so using a ternary would be pointless. Otherwise, it is unclear what you are asking for and what you're expecting.

Comment: yes i have tried many time to fix that but i did not find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use state for storing your inital default value.
make two css classes with different styling

```
const [sty,setSty]=useState("default css class name here")
```

if you have some event then change it state set classname of your css.Now for your else part just change the state or make another state for storing name of diffeent css class

```
{value && showBtn?<span title={value} className={sty}>{value}<button  type="button"  onClick={handelClick} className="float-right  rounded-md text-blue-500 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none " className={"big-size-file"?'marginTop:-17px':'margTop:11px'}>
                            <svg
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                className="h-3 w-3 z-100"
                                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                fill="currentColor"      
                            >
                                <path
                                    fillRule="evenodd"
                                    d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                                    clipRule="evenodd"
                                />
                            </svg>
                        </button></span>:<span>No file chosen</span>}
```

Comment: i solve that doubt in this way

Comment: Always open for help